# iframe doesn't display Microsoft Booking

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe

[image: This is what it displays]

This is what it displays instead of the booking website.
Here is the code

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
const Appointment = () => {
    return (
    <iframe src='https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/bookings/' />
    )
}

export default Appointment
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Any errors in console? - there is not much to go by here

Comment: @blurfus No..only "<iframe> elements must have a unique title property". Btw, I just did inspect element on the iframe and the dimensions for the html code inside the website was 300x0. I set the a style="height: 1000px !important" inside the html code through inspect element, but still it shows that gray bg..And I have that same gray bg on the booking website too, just on the right and left sides.

Comment: and the URL, if you copy/paste it into a browser (private mode) shows the desired output?

Comment: @blurfus Yep it shows the desired output...

Comment: They may be preventing their page from being iframed...

Comment: I am guessing it's a CORS issue but w/o any other details, I am afraid it's only a guess

Comment: @blurfus I just noticed that it works on Microsoft Edge. But not on Google

Comment: @blurfus And I totally missed out a console error. It says "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://outlook.office365.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame." Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: as mentioned by @Nikki9696 - they are preventing the page from being iframed. There is nothing on your end you can do to change that.

Comment: Damn..alright then

Answer (score 0):

You are required to give height and width to the iframe

```
import React from 'react'
const Appointment = () => {
    return (
    <iframe src='https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/bookings/' height:'800px' width:'100%'
/>
 )
}
```

export default Appointment